# Заполнить массив заданной длины различными простыми числами

Tags: c#, алгоритм

Нужно заполнить массив заданной длины различными простыми числами. Вот кривая недореализация (детали в комментариях):

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int[] arr = new int[10];
        Work ob = new Work();
        ob.Go(arr);

        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
class Work
{
    public void Go(int[] arr)
    {
        int temp = 2;
        for(int i = 0; i < arr.Length; i++)
        {
            if (i == 0) { arr[i] = temp; continue; }
            if (i == 1) { arr[i] = (temp = temp + 1); temp++; continue; }
            if ((1 == (temp / temp)) && ((temp / 1) == temp))
            {         //это проверка на "простое ли число" (ошибочна) не хватает условия "которое не делится без остатка ни на одно другое целое положительное число"
                                        // поэтому всё решение и разваливается. Собственно, как это реализовать???
                arr[i] = temp;  temp++; }                               
        }
        for(int j = 0; j < arr.Length; j++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(arr[j]);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `(1 == (temp / temp)) && ((temp / 1) == temp)` - а что, бывает по-другому?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Мои "пять центов".:)

```
class Work
{
    public static void Go(int[] a)
    {
        int value = 1;

        for (int i = 0; i < a.Length; i++)
        {
            bool prime = true;
            do
            {
                ++value;
                for (int j = 0; j < i && a[j] <= value / 2 && (prime = value % a[j] != 0); ++j) ;
            } while (!prime);

            a[i] = value;
        }
    }
}
```

Так как метод `Go` статический, то не надо создавать объект класса `Work`. Достаточно вызывать метод следующим образом:

```
Work.Go( arr );
```

Например, массив из 10 элементов будет инициализирован последовательно следующими значениями

```
 2 3 5 7 11 13 17 19 23 29
```

Принцип работы метода следующий. Если уже начальные элементы массива заполнены, как, например,

```
2 3 5 7
```

то чтобы получить следующее по возрастанию простое число и присвоить его следующему элементу массива, берется значение последнего заполненного элемента, в данном случае 7, увеличивается на 1, то есть получаем 8, и это число последовательно делится на предыдущее простые числа, хранящиеся в массиве. Если это число не делится нацело на все предшествующие простые числа, то значит оно - простое число. Если же оно делится на одно из простых чисел (8 делится нацело на 2), то данное число снова увеличивается на 1, и процесс продолжается пока не будет найдено простое число.  Для данного примера таким простым числом будет 11, так как оно не делится ни на 2, ни на 3, ни на 5. Проверять его делимость на 7 не имеет смысла так как 7 больше 11 / 2 и, очевидно, не будет нацело делиться на 7.

Comment: Реализация отлично работает. Если не затруднит, добавьте пожалуйста комментарии для лучшего понимания кода. Не до конца понятно использование столь длинного условия для for, а также переменных value и prime. Это обычная практика - исп-ие дополнительных переменных?

Comment: @Олег  Мне представляется, что алгоритм метода настолько прозрачен, что комментарии не требуются. Тем не менее я дополнил свой ответ комментарием, правда не знаю, насколько он полезен.

Answer (score 3):

Я предлагаю проверять простоту числа, пробегая не по всем, а только по уже найденным простым числам, меньшим корня из `x`.
Пример для получения первых `10` простых чисел:

```
List<int> primes = new List<int> { 2, 3 };

int i = primes.Last() + 2;
while (primes.Count < 10)
{
    foreach (int p in primes)
    {
        if (i % p == 0)
            break;
        if (p * p > i)
        {
            primes.Add(i);
            break;
        }
    }
    i += 2;
}
```

После его выполнения, в коллекции `primes` будет ровно `10` первых простых чисел.

Тот же метод, но с использованием LINQ:

```
List<int> primes = new List<int> { 2, 3 };

int i = primes.Last() + 2;
while (primes.Count < 10)
{
    int n = i;
    if (primes.TakeWhile(p => n % p != 0).Any(p => p * p > n))
    {
        primes.Add(i);
    }
    i += 2;
}
```

Comment: Идея хорошая, но разделение на две части этого кода мне не нравится. Лучше бы назвал функцию AddNextPrime и поместил цикл while в неё.

Comment: `if (i * i >= x)` - брр.. Оно тут правильно, потому что остаток проверяется раньше, но сама идея - при равенстве же число не простое.

Comment: @Qwertiy учел ваши рекомендации.

Answer (score 2):

Во-первых, было бы лучше реализовать решето Эратосфена.

Во-вторых, проверка на простоту делается как-то так:

```
bool IsPrime(int x)
{
  if (x % 2 == 0)
    return x == 2;

  for (int q=3; q*q<=x; q+=2)
    if (x % q == 0)
      return false;

  return true;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

хватит жечь процессорное время на вычисление того, что уже давно вычислено!

```
var result = new WebClient()
    .DownloadString("https://primes.utm.edu/lists/small/1000.txt")
    .Split()
    .SelectMany(r => {int n; return int.TryParse(r, out n) ? new int[]{n} : new int[0]; })
    .Take(100).ToArray();
```

Answer (score 0):

Зависит от того, какое ограничение и требования на простые числа.

Если числа совсем маленькие, то можно использовать метод поиска полного перебора до корня квадратного от числа, если до миллиона, то можно использовать [решето Эратосфена](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A0%D0%B5%D1%88%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%BE_%D0%AD%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%84%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B0).

Если нужны числа порядка `2^32` и выше, то можно использовать [вероятностный метод Миллера-Рабина](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A2%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82_%D0%9C%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%BB%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0_%E2%80%94_%D0%A0%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B0).

Answer (score 0):

Вот относительно короткая LINQ-версия последовательности простых чисел:

```
static IEnumerable<int> Primes()
{
    return Enumerable.Range(2, int.MaxValue - 2)
                     .Where(i => ParallelEnumerable.Range(2, Math.Max(0, (int)Math.Sqrt(i) - 1))
                                                   .All(j => i % j != 0));
}
```